# assign dynamic ids to lightning component dom element and then access it in lightning js controller/helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, css

I know that we cannot assign expressions to the aura : id. It should be hard coded string literal, as per the salesforce documentation. Also, we cannot use html Id, as document.getElementById is no more supported. I saw some posts related to this where it was suggested to dynamically create the component. But that go well with the below scenario. Is there any workaround for this ? Basically i have a checkbox and a text inside an iteration element, in a lightning component. when the checkbox is checked, i want to strike out the corresponding text. Below is the code snippet.

Component :

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.somelist}" var="val"> 
   <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="{!val.id}" onclick="{!c.somefunction}"/>
   <a id="{!val.id}"> some text </a>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller :

---

```
somefunction: function(component, event, helper) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    // is there a way, i can get the anchor tag element and add the css 
    class strikeText to it ?    
}
```

CSS :

---

```
.THIS .strikeText{
    text-decoration:line-through; 
}
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This statement **we cannot use html Id, as document.getElementById is no more supported**  is not true.  you can use document.getElementById and other supported DOM API in Lightnig component.

Comment: I get the undefined value when trying to access by document.getElementById. Post locker service, this does not seems to be working.

Comment: Just now checked in my dev org. `document.getElementById()` works for me with locker in place.

Comment: Thats true Praveen, It does work. It was some problem with the id and i had to append another character to it, to get it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom html attributes to your checkbox. For example:

```
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="{!c.somefunction}" 
 data-anchorId="{!val.Id}" />
```

Then in your controller, you can use the `document.getElementById()` Javascript function to find the anchor depending on your custom attribute:

```
var anchorId = event.target.getAttribute("data-anchorId");
var anchor = document.getElementById(anchorId);
anchor.className += " strikeText";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin.  The DOM which i get by event.target is the checkbox element. However, i need to add the css class to the anchor tag, which has the value "Some Text". Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: @Yashmith Sorry I didn't understand. I updated my answer.